# Choose map frame name in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts, map-frame

In the ArcGIS Pro toolbox, what would be the parameter to set so that we can add a drop-down menu to choose the map frame name?

[image]

Comment: Is this for a Python script tool, a Python Toolbox tool or perhaps a Model tool?

Answer (score 1):

Set the params index number to the parameter for the dropdown. The zero below is for the first parameter.

```
def initializeParameters(self):
    # Customize parameter properties. 
    # This gets called when the tool is opened.
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
    map_list = [mf.name for mf in aprx.listMaps()]
    self.params[0].filter.list = map_list
    return
```

For map frame elements. The below assumes one Layout in the APRX.

```
def initializeParameters(self):
    # Customize parameter properties. 
    # This gets called when the tool is opened.
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
    lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
    mapf_list = [mf.name for mf in lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT")]
    self.params[0].filter.list = mapf_list
    return
```